# Error 405 : POST method not found while Sending JSON to Java Controller (Ajax)

Tags: javascript, java, json, model-view-controller

I've a problem with sending JSON data to my Java Controller.

I have the following methode in my JSP file :

```
$.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "/addPerson.html",
              data: JSON.stringify({
                    aanvraag_id : chosenAanvraagId,
                    sharingbox_id : chosenSharingboxId
                }),
              contentType: 'application/json',
              success: function(data) {
              alert("de operatie is uitgevoerd");
              }
            });
```

This is my controller:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = { "/addPerson" }, method = RequestMethod.POST , headers = {"Content-type=application/json"})
@ResponseBody
public JsonResponse addPerson(@RequestBody Person person) {
    System.out.println(person.toString());
    return new JsonResponse("OK", "");
}
```

When I call the ajax method I get a error

```
Status Code 405 :  "POST method not found."
```

Anyone who knows what the problem is here?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: in your URL you are calling "addPerson.html" this can not be "html"

Comment: why `.html` extension used just after `URL` ?  @Mathias

Comment: @Mathias I must say your error message will be change after edited of your url key in ajax Statement. Please see carefully now your message is `Method Not Allowed` right?? then why down-vote for this ???

Comment: @VikrantKashyap the message is indeed not allowed. Do you have a solution?

Comment: Show us your MVC configuration and your controller itself. Post a [MCVE]. Do your logs show Spring MVC registering your controller?

Answer (score -1):

you have to change the url in your JSP

```
 $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "/addPerson.html",  // you can't write .html here, it should just be "/addPerson"
          data: JSON.stringify({
                aanvraag_id : chosenAanvraagId,
                sharingbox_id : chosenSharingboxId
            }),
          contentType: 'application/json',
          success: function(data) {
          alert("de operatie is uitgevoerd");
          }
        });
```

Comment: Okay thank you . I still have a 405 error though. https://www.dropbox.com/s/pj2tqj35dx31e44/Screenshot%202016-05-18%2015.29.04.png?dl=0